# Spring cloud stream kafka transactions in producer side

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We have a spring cloud stream app using Kafka. The requirement is that on the producer side the list of messages needs to be put in a topic in a transaction. There is no consumer for the messages in the same app. When i initiated the transaction using spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transaction-id prefix, I am facing the error that there is no subscriber for the dispatcher and a total number of partitions obtained from the topic is less than the transaction configured. The app is not able to obtain the partitions for the topic in transaction mode. Could you please tell if I am missing anything. I will post detailed logs tomorrow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show your code and configuration as well as the versions you are using.

Producer-only transactions are [discussed in the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-transactional-binder).

> Enable transactions by setting spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix to a non-empty value, e.g. tx-. When used in a processor application, the consumer starts the transaction; any records sent on the consumer thread participate in the same transaction. When the listener exits normally, the listener container will send the offset to the transaction and commit it. A common producer factory is used for all producer bindings configured using spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.producer.* properties; individual binding Kafka producer properties are ignored.
>
> If you wish to use transactions in a source application, or from some arbitrary thread for producer-only transaction (e.g. @Scheduled method), you must get a reference to the transactional producer factory and define a KafkaTransactionManager bean using it.

```java
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(BinderFactory binders) {
    ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> pf = ((KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binders.getBinder(null,
            MessageChannel.class)).getTransactionalProducerFactory();
    return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(pf);
}
```

> Notice that we get a reference to the binder using the BinderFactory; use null in the first argument when there is only one binder configured. If more than one binder is configured, use the binder name to get the reference. Once we have a reference to the binder, we can obtain a reference to the ProducerFactory and create a transaction manager.
>
> Then you would just normal Spring transaction support, e.g. TransactionTemplate or @Transactional, for example:

```java
public static class Sender {

    @Transactional
    public void doInTransaction(MessageChannel output, List<String> stuffToSend) {
        stuffToSend.forEach(stuff -> output.send(new GenericMessage<>(stuff)));
    }

}
```

If you wish to synchronize producer-only transactions with those from some other transaction manager, use a ChainedTransactionManager.

Comment: Thanks Gary,

Versions used:
spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-kafka-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-function-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-amqp-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar
pring-kafka-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-spring-service-connector-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Application.java
-----------------------
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude= {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,RabbitAutoConfiguration.class}) 
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
  
  
  new CloudFactory().getCloud();
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }
 
}

Comment: application.yml
--------------------------------

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers: eesdsdasdadad-df.net:9092
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.destination.binder: kafka
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.destination.destination:  events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.destination.contentType: application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.destination.producer.requiredGroups: events

#spring.cloud.stream.bindings.destination.producer.partitionKeyExpression: payload.keyNumber
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix: events-

Comment: Edit the question instead. It's too hard to read stuff like this in comments.

Comment: I am using @EnableTransactionManagement annotation to the same logic to send messages to the destination

Comment: When i introduced transaction by adding transaction id prefix I am facing the following error.

Comment: 2019-09-27 16:23:25 [main] ERROR o.s.c.stream.binding.BindingService - Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds
org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Cannot initialize binder:
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.getPartitionsForTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:451)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The number of expected partitions was: 1, but 0 has been found instead
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.lambda$getPartitionsForTopic$2(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:441)
 at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
 at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
 at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.getPartitionsForTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:404)

Comment: I am facing compilation error when adding the code you posted.

Comment: @Bean
 public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(BinderFactory binders) {
     ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> pf = ((KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binders.getBinder(null,
             MessageChannel.class)).getTransactionalProducerFactory();
     return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(pf);
 }

Comment: The method getTransactionalProducerFactory() is undefined for the type KafkaMessageChannelBinder

Comment: Please edit the question and delete all these comments.

Comment: Support for producer-only transactions was added in the 2.1.4 version of the binder.