# spring-cloud-stream - Kafka producer prefix unique per node

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to send something to Kafka topic in producer-only (not in read-write process) transaction using output-channel.
I read documentation and another topic on StackOverflow ([Spring cloud stream kafka transactions in producer side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152618/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-transactions-in-producer-side/58156158#58156158)).

Problem is that i need to set unique transactionIdPrefix per node.
Any suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way...

```java
@Component
class TxIdCustomizer implements EnvironmentAware {

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.transaction.transactionIdPrefix",
                UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ((StandardEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources()
                .addLast(new PropertiesPropertySource("txId", properties));
    }

}
```